# How to prevent cross-world lines in ggplot world map?

Tags: r, ggplot2, great-circle, ggmap, antimeridian

I'm having issues displaying 'great circles' paths and polygons in ggmap, an extension of ggplot2. Please enter the following code to replicate my issues:

https://gist.github.com/Robinlovelace/379e0a3db23b53965c73

```
# load packages we'll be using
x <- c("ggmap", "geosphere", "sp")
lapply(x, library, character.only = TRUE)

download.file("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15008199/tmp/origins.csv", "origins.csv", method = "wget")

origins <- read.csv("origins.csv")
os <- SpatialPoints(coords = origins,
proj4string = CRS("+init=epsg:4326"))
  dest <- geocode("Leura")
destp <- SpatialPoints(coords = matrix(c(dest$lon, dest$lat), nrow = 1),
  proj4string = CRS("+init=epsg:4326"))

path <- NULL
for(i in 1:nrow(coordinates(os))){
  path_tmp <- gcIntermediate(coordinates(os[i, ])[2:3], p2 = dest)
  path_tmp <- data.frame(path_tmp)
  path_tmp$person <- i
  path <- rbind(path, path_tmp)
}

wrld <- borders("world", colour="gray50", fill="gray50")

# plot the result
ggplot() + wrld +
  geom_point(data = origins, aes(lon, lat)) +
  geom_path(data = path, aes(lon, lat, group = person)) +
  coord_fixed(ratio = 1)
```

[image: world1]

As shown, all lines crossing 180 degree longitude jump across the whole world, instead of 'going round the back' as it should. Any ideas of a quick fix?

Even when the destination is moved to the centre of map there are still problems:

[image]

On a wider note, are there any prospects of the bug in which projected geom_polygons fail? - This issue is mentioned on the [moribund](https://github.com/dkahle/ggmap/graphs/contributors) ggmap GitHub [issue tracker](https://github.com/dkahle/ggmap/issues/6) and described on in a [blog post](http://robinlovelace.net/2014/06/22/great-circles-in-rworldmap-ggplot2.html).

Beginning to wonder if it would be easier to do this in base graphics...

**Edit: Example II**

## Download data

```
x <- c("ggmap", "geosphere", "sp")
lapply(x, library, character.only = TRUE)

download.file("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15008199/tmp/origins.csv", "origins.csv", method = "wget")

origins <- read.csv("origins.csv")
os <- SpatialPoints(coords = origins,
proj4string = CRS("+init=epsg:4326"))
dest <- geocode("Leura")
destp <- SpatialPoints(coords = matrix(c(dest$lon, dest$lat), nrow = 1),
proj4string = CRS("+init=epsg:4326"))

path <- NULL
# for(i in 1:2){ # for testing
for(i in 1:nrow(coordinates(os))){
pathl <- gcIntermediate(coordinates(os[i, ])[2:3], p2 = dest, breakAtDateLine = T)
cl <- class(pathl)
path_tmp <- matrix(unlist(pathl, use.names = T ), ncol = 2)
path_tmp <- data.frame(path_tmp)
path_tmp$person <- i
# ifelse(cl == "matrix", path_tmp$person <- i , no = path_tmp$person <- paste(i, c(rep(1, nrow(pathl[[1]])), rep(2, nrow(pathl[[2]]))), sep = "."))
path <- rbind(path, path_tmp)
}

wrld <- borders("world", colour="gray50", fill="gray50")

# plot the result
ggplot() + wrld +
geom_point(data = origins, aes(lon, lat)) +
geom_path(data = path, aes(X1, X2, group = person)) +
coord_fixed(ratio = 1)
```

I've got it working by preventing lines from crossing the longitude extremes and following code described [here](http://web.stanford.edu/~cengel/cgi-bin/anthrospace/great-circles-on-a-recentered-worldmap-in-ggplot) but still not found a solution to the original question.

[image]

Comment: It's no easier in base though really. The fundamental problem is described well here http://bost.ocks.org/mike/example/ and here http://vimeo.com/106198518. Any fix in R depends heavily on the data you want to use the way you want to plot.

Comment: but try the argument "breakAtDateLine" for the gcIntermediate function (and *please* provide reproducible code - it's just not useable as is).

Comment: Hi @mdsumner, thanks for the information - I forgot to load the 3 packages used in this example. Updated code should now work, let me know. Just trying it with the breakAtDate argument, looking positive.

Comment: Still not working with the 'breakAtDate' argument I'm afraid: reproducible example here: https://gist.github.com/Robinlovelace/838178ef83561a6eb713 . Please provide a reproducible answer!

Comment: Why put the example elsewhere?

Comment: Why focus on such petty details? I've added the code to the question for your benefit though! Does it work for you now? Thanks.

Comment: @RobinLovelace You probably know James Cheshire from UCL given you have a paper with him. He created this type of map. You may want to ask him. I replicated his map, but asking him would be much easier and faster. BTW, thanks for helping me for proj4string issue the other day.

Comment: @jazzurro I've already asked him f2f - hence asking the big wide world! Seems there's no easy solution ...

Comment: @RobinLovelace I see. Do you want a graphic like one I have in my SO profile?

Comment: @jazzurro yes that's definitely the kind of thing I'm after.

Comment: @RobinLovelace Got it. Let me drop you an email later. Most likely tomorrow. It is hard to explain everything here.

Comment: @RobinLovelace - any chance you might post what you wound up doing as an answer?