# R spTransform polygon that crosses dateline

Tags: coordinate-system, r, sp

I have created polygons with CRS = UTM (see [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/294317/r-raster-extract-weighted-mean-within-circle-of-specific-radius)), which I need to transform to latitude/longitude. Some of my polygons cross the dateline, which causes the transformation to create a polygon that crosses the entire globe.

```
library(sp)
library(rgeos)

points <- data.frame(x = c(-179.5, 0), y = c(-50, -30))
coordinates(points) <- ~x+y
proj4string(points) <- '+init=epsg:4326'

points_sp <- spTransform(points, CRS('+init=epsg:32621')) # wrong zone, but ignored for example
# expand point to circle
circles <- gBuffer(points_sp, width = 1e+5)
# transform back to WGS84
circles_latlon <- spTransform(circles, CRS(proj4string(points)))

par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
plot(circles, axes = TRUE, main = 'UTM')
plot(circles_latlon, axes = TRUE, main = 'WGS84')
```

[image]

Is there a solution to split the polygons? Or and alternative solution that takes care of the dateline issue?

Comment: Related?: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/122494/how-to-prevent-cross-world-lines-in-ggplot-world-map

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using `st_wrap_dateline` from the **sf** package?

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.6.1, GDAL 2.2.4, proj.4 4.9.3
point1 <- st_point(c(-179.5, -50))
point2 <- st_point(c(0, -30))
points <- st_sfc(point1, point2, crs = 4236)

points_trans <- st_transform(points, 32621)
circles <- st_buffer(points_trans, 100000)
circles_latlon <- st_transform(circles, 4326)
circles_latlon2 <- st_wrap_dateline(circles_latlon, options = c("WRAPDATELINE=YES"))

par(mfrow = c(1, 3))
plot(circles, axes = TRUE, main = 'UTM')
plot(circles_latlon, axes = TRUE, main = 'WGS84')
plot(circles_latlon2, axes = TRUE, main = 'WGS84 with wrapdateline')
```

[image]

```r
# check the results
mapview::mapview(circles_latlon2)
```

You can convert the output to a Spatial object with:

```r
circles_latlon2_sp <- as(circles_latlon2, "Spatial")
```

Comment: Thanks, this could work if I convert back to spatialPolygons after (in order to use it with `raster::extract`). However, I get: `Warning message: In CPL_wrap_dateline(x, options, quiet) :  GDAL Error 6: GEOS support not enabled.`  When I load `sf` I get `Linking to GEOS 3.6.1, GDAL 2.1.3, proj.4 4.9.3`. Any clue how to address this?

Comment: Thanks again. The conversion wasn't the problem. It was the GDAL error, which causes the `circles_latlon2 <- st_wrap_dateline(circles_latlon, options = c("WRAPDATELINE=YES"))` to fail. Do you have a suggestion how to enable GEOS support?

Comment: Sadly, I do not have an answer to this issue..

Comment: I solved it. See [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52335853/r-sf-how-to-enable-geos-support)